# magento imported products with magmi are not visible on the website

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a CSV file and it takes ages to import it with magento standard interface, import is ok. I tried to use open source solution called "Magmi" which imports the same file in seconds when magento takes days. The problem is that if the file is imported with magmi, products are not visible on the website, even though they show in admin panel. Does somebody know the CSV structure (obligatory fields) for a successful Magmi import to happen?

Comment: Check whether the product is "in stock" and status is "Enabled".Have you specified these in csv file?

Comment: I have a field status with values "Enabled", but I don't have a field "in stock". Should it be "in_stock"? And what should be the value of this field?

Comment: There is no "in_stock" name.If "qty" > 0,products will not appear.Make sure quantity is set.

Comment: If you mean "qty" in admin panel, products imported with magento interface have 0 quantity value and they still show on the website.

Comment: Have you specified "qty" in csv file.If you haven't, quantity is set to 0 and products will not show.

Comment: I inserted qty column in csv file, import goes well, qty is shown in admin panel but products still don't show on the website... It seams that qty is not essential column.

Comment: How can I import products images for multi-store, may i know csv header columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reindex (System -> Index Management) after importing with magmi: not sure exactly which indexes are required, one I know for sure is Product Flat Data, even if you don't use the flat catalog.
As for the csv structure, export all products to have an example.

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked, but the problem now is that the image of the product doesn't show on the website...

Comment: have you installed the plugin for images?

Answer (score 2):

magmi automatically indexes "Category Products" (catalog_category_product) and "Catalog URL Rewrites" (catalog_url), but only if you use the "on the fly" indexer plugin. However, in order for the products to show up on the frontend, you need to run the "**product price**" indexer (catalog_product_price). It's one of the quickest indexes, so a full reindex is overkill, specially if you have many products.

remember you can execute the reindexing via command line to save some time. Inside /magento/shell/ execute 
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price

Just type "php indexer.php" and you'll get a list of available commands.